# Best PHP newsletter tool

Tags: php, phpmailer, newsletter

In one of my web portal there are more than 1000 users . I need a news letter for every week for all these users ... My system ( web account ) crashed when I tried with a for loop . Can you please suggest me a tool or code for doing that ?

Thanks in aadvance

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901895/how-to-use-php-mail-function-without-crashing-the-server/3901932#3901932

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know [phplist](http://www.phplist.com/) is a valid opensource solution for php mailing lists.